# Insert invisible but selectable text (to pass PDF word number detection by machine)

Tags: fonts, color, fontsize

My homework was asked for more than 25,000 words in a non-character language. I have a lot of mathematical formulas, nearly 25 pages,  but due to the computer stupid detection mechanism, all mathematical derivations can not be counted as words. Is there any way to pass the automated word count detection, like adding invisible text to be readable by the detection program?

Comment: `\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{white}{please count these words}}` ?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
1\foreach \a in {1,...,1000} {\llap{1}}
\end{document}`